# Serial communication in c#

Tags: c#

I have made a simple windows form with a ComboBox, TextBox and two Buttons to setup a serial protocol with my hardware.

However, whenever I send something I do get reply from hardware but C# doesn't display it. Instead it gives an exception saying that the operation has timed out. I even used an oscilloscope to check if I received something and it was positive. But C# doesn't display the code as stated before.

I am attaching my code below. Anyhelp would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    string buffer;
    public SerialPort myComPort = new SerialPort();
    delegate void setTextCallback(string text);


    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().Contains("(COM"))
                {

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(queryObj["Caption"]);
                }
            }
            comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[0].ToString();
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void setText(string text)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            setTextCallback tcb = new setTextCallback(setText);
            this.Invoke(tcb, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }

    void myComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string myString = myComPort.ReadLine();
            setText(myString);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myComPort.Close();

          //  button1.Enabled = false;
            string name = comboBox1.Text;
            string[] words = name.Split('(', ')');
            myComPort.PortName = words[1];
            myComPort.ReadTimeout = 5000;
           // myComPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            myComPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myComPort.DataBits = 8;
            myComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myComPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            myComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(myComPort_DataReceived);

            myComPort.Open();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myComPort.WriteLine("?GV1\r");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the reply contain a newline? If not, `ReadLine()` will not work.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken you might need to declare a new event handler for DataRecieved.

Comment: set a breakpoint when you read from the serialport (myComPort.ReadLine) and check myComPort.IsOpen aswell as myComPort.BytesToRead > 0. what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

> ### [It say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)
>
> ...The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received...

Try something like:

```
    private static void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent error with closed port to appears
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
            return;
        // read data
        if (_port.BytesToRead >= 1)
        {
            // ...
            // read data into a buffer _port.ReadByte()

            DataReceived(sender, e);
        }

        // ...
        // if buffer contains data, process them
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this url:

http://csharp.simpleserial.com/

And this url for WMI:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32330/A-Useful-WMI-Tool-How-To-Find-USB-to-Serial-Adapto